# android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14 error

Tags: android, xamarin

Keep getting this error when I run my application. It crashes on base.OnCreate (bundle); This started happening when I updated my android support library.
I am using xamarin. All my compotes are up to date and so is my xamarin studio
Don't know what else to do

Comment: Can you give more details about the error?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by recreating the project and made the file path shorter
I hope this can help somebody else too